# Custom RESTful api GET request only works if user is already logged in, although _access has been set to 'TRUE'

Tags: 8

Controller outputs a json response. On local machine it works fine weather user is logged in or not. But on the server if the use is not logged in to drupal the single page application that fetches unpublished nodes using ajax call gets `503 (Service Unavailable)` error. I have done what this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) says and set _access: 'TRUE' in the routing.yml file and tried couple of other things but no luck. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: 503 isn't access denied, it's an error. check your drupal/php/apache error logs.

Comment: @Berdir, it turned out to be so, because the site was under maintenance!
don't know what to say :) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem of no json output was, it turned out, because the site was under maintenance mode! And like Berdir said 503 is not access denied error!